# Add to cart quantity dynamic

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have AJAX add to cart with input field where the quantity is.

```
esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
```

If i put in the shop page quantity on 30 and add to cart it only adds 1 because of the code above^. How can I make this dynamic by saying add to cart of howmany is filled in the .qty field

Full code:
**quantity-input.php**

```
<div class="quantity">
<input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
<input type="number" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" <?php if ( is_numeric( $min_value ) ) : ?>min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php if ( is_numeric( $max_value ) ) : ?>max="<?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?>"<?php endif; ?> name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php _ex( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
<input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery( function( $ ) {
       $('.minus').on('click', function() {
          $(this).next('input').val((i, v) => parseInt(v, 10) - 1);
        });

        $('.plus').on('click', function() {
          $(this).prev('input').val((i, v) => parseInt(v, 10) + 1);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**functions.php**

```
/**
 * Adjust the quantity input values
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        // Get the necessary classes
        $class = implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
            'button',
            'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
        ) ) );

        // Adding embeding <form> tag and the quantity field
        $html = sprintf( '%s%s<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>%s',
            '<form class="cart">',
            woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false ),
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
            $product->add_to_cart_text(),
            '</form>'
        );
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: What is the full code? (can you show a larger sample of code). Where is the $quantity value being set and how (e.g. with what value, from where such as $_POST, $_GET etc). Also I suggest showing the AJAX (JavaScript).

Comment: please see my edit